# What are some reasons UINavigationController would silently fail on presentViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

### What could cause `presentViewController:animated:completion:` to silently fail?

I have a `UINavgiationViewController` with *ViewController A* as its root.
When VC A's `viewDidAppear` is called (after being pushed) it uses the `UINavgiationViewController` to modally *present* *ViewController B* (using `presentViewController`).

ViewController B's `modalPresentationStyle` has been set to `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext` before being presented.

**Sporadically `presentViewController:animated:completion:` silently fails** (no errors/warnings), and its completion block isn't executed. I've confirmed that before being called, the `UINavgiationViewController`'s `presentedViewController` is always nil. What could cause this behavior?

Comment: Why do you need to use the navigation controller to present ViewController B? You can present ViewController B on ViewController A, even if ViewController A is in a navigation controller.

Comment: @neilvillareal because I am trying to present ViewController B modally over the current context.

Comment: Wrapping the present method in a block called on the main thread appears to prevent failures, even though I've confirmed that all the calls do happen on the main thread already.